# Is Windows GTK version compatible?

Tags: compatibility, gtk2

I just upgraded GTK version from 2.10.11 to 2.24.10. I found that my codes that run well in GTK 2.10.11 failed in that of 2.24.10. The environment is exactly same except the GTK version:

- MinGW + MSYS in Windows. The gcc version is 4.7.2.
- The latest GTK2 Windows version is downloaded from the GTK official web site.

Followed is a small code. In GTK 2.24.10, when switching pages, the entry in each page is gray or to say "insensitive". But it worked well in 2.10.11 -- the entry is editable. So, is Windows GTK version compatible?

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>

gint main (gint argc, gchar *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window, *notebook, *entry, *title;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);

  notebook = gtk_notebook_new ();
  gtk_notebook_set_tab_pos (GTK_NOTEBOOK (notebook), GTK_POS_TOP);

  entry = gtk_entry_new ();
  gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY (entry), "123");
  title = gtk_label_new ("foo");
  gtk_notebook_append_page (GTK_NOTEBOOK (notebook), entry, title);

  entry = gtk_entry_new ();
  gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY (entry), "456");
  title = gtk_label_new ("bar");
  gtk_notebook_append_page (GTK_NOTEBOOK (notebook), entry, title);

  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), notebook);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 400, 400);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT:

I think the latest gtk win32 version -- 2.24.10 has bugs. Just run `gtk-demo`, then push the tab `Source`, then go back to the tab `Info`, then the tab `Info` turns grey and you can't see the contents in the tab. But this doesn't occur in the version 2.22.1. Maybe I should report the bug to GTK but I don't know if it is a bug or I miss something.

Comment: I tested your code in my gtk 2.24.28 and I don't have entry controls insensitive, are you sure that's your hole code?

Comment: Do you work in MinGW? I can make screen shot for each case, but I don't know where I can put the images.

Comment: I tested on gcc 5.2, and I don't think is nothing to do with the compiler version.

Comment: I am working in MinGW. The latest version of gcc is 4.8.1. Do you think gcc version is the culprit? I don't think gcc version is the point.